# Polymorphic SERVICES with WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, oop, polymorphism

I am trying to hold to the DRY principle in developing WCF services for our application, but I seem to be going down a lot of rabbit holes.  My original idea was to have an abstract base class to hold code common to all services, and have derived classes for each concrete service, but cannot seem to get VS2012 to play nice.

Whenever you create a service class, it INSISTS on putting the contract (interface) and implementation classes in the same project, and trying to pull those apart seems to hose up the wiring that VS has done under the hood, so then things break.

I guess all my years of "classic" OO design are getting in the way, I wanted to have the concrete services derive from the interface class AND the abstract base class, but I'm not having a lot of luck.  I have found questions/blogs on having polymorphic DATA types used by services, but have not found examples of polymorphic SERVICE types.  Can anyone point me?

Thanks,
Peter

UPDATE: Perhaps I am over-thinking the whole thing, I am actually NOT trying to have inheritance for OPERATIONS since a composite approach would make more sense, I just want to keep common code in one place (obviously...), and the whole "static helper class" approach always feels "dirty" to me, kind of defeating the whole OO approach...I am hoping I can simply have the contrete service classes inherit from an abstract base class that is NOT necessarily the implementation of any particular service contract, but is just a way to keep the code DRY...

ALSO: I am trying to use the Template pattern for the service classes, since the overall structure of the services is so similar (devil is always in the details...)

Comment: Yea, if you don't follow the template it won't work, but that does not mean you HAVE to follow the template. Just fix the environment after you create a new project or if you are making projects frequently [make your own template project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/s365byhx.aspx) and have visual studio use that. You have kind of fallen in to a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377), you should either [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19035608/edit) or ask a new one about the difficulties you are having doing WCF and base classes.

Comment: If inheritance is not working for you you might try delegation, it is a few more lines of code but maybe less of a headache.

Comment: What common functions are you looking to inherit from the abstract base?

Comment: Logging, loading DI (Unity) container(s), instantiating Exception handlers - housekeeping stuff.  Like I added in an edit, I think it will work fine inheriting from a "generic" abstract base class that is NOT the implementation of a particular contract (interface.)  I'm working on that now...

Answer (score 4):

You can separate the interface classes and implementation classes into different projects. One easy way to do is to create the projects manually and write/copy the code as you would for any .NET  OO solution.

The following is a set of samples provided by Microsoft...

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21459

You should be able to dig into the samples and find one that meets your requirement.